# Can I use MTM from VS2012 with visualstudio.com's TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager

I'm trying to create some MTM coded ui tests and hook it up to my visualstudio.com tfs instance. I haven't had any luck getting it to connect. Is it possible to use microsoft's cloud tfs or azure of some sort rather than installing TFS on my intranet?

Comment: What happens when you try and connect to your cloud TFS?

Comment: it says `Unable to connect to server 'imaginarydevelopment.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection'.  Check that the server name is correct and that you have access to the server.

TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server http://imaginarydevelopment.visualstudio.com:8080/tfs.
Technical information (for administrator):
  Unable to connect to the remote server`

Comment: This works fine for me? What version of MTM/VS are you using? Do you have the latest updates? [2010](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2736182) / [2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39305)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MTM connects to Team Foundation Service just fine.  From your comment it looks like you're trying to connect via http:// not https://

Use https://imaginarydevelopment.visualstudio.com and you should connect up just fine (note that you don't need to specify the project collection either)